# Can we add computed column in mysql table without trigger or procedure like ms sql server

Tags: mysql

I have a need to calculate to dates day difference. And i am expecting the calculated record come to my column without additional query....

MS Sql fulfill my need but same thing is not happening in mysql, so the concern is? Is it possible to do in mysql

```
ALTER TABLE `transx`.`reservation_rooms` 
ADD COLUMN `days` tinyint(2) AS DATEDIFF(`start`, `end`)
```

Comment: Yes, MySQL has this feature. What version are you using, and what exactly is the problem?

Comment: In MySQL 5.7 [generated columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html#create-table-generated-columns) will be available.

Comment: It is available only in Mysql 5.7 and it's GA version is not released till now as it's milestone version is available at this time.

Comment: I am using 5.5.42

Thank you guys